# Fluid Mantaflow Simulation Effector not behaving correctly

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I'm new to Blender's fluid mantaflow, I am currently trying to get the fluid to collide with the main effector, and then flow to a mug, but it seems like both the effector have too dense collision (I guess?). Also the liquid appears to be quite wonky and behaving not calmly even after adjusting the resolution.

My blender version is: 2.93.2.
[image: FLuid not touching effector]

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eiibyql227ruflr/try5.blend?dl=0)'s the attached file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase the resolution in your domain. If you increase it to 100 you will get this:

[image]

Comment: Oh thankyou very much Chris, that actually helps alot!

Comment: You are welcome